# Powershell DSC Configuration: Installing selective Windows Feature

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, dsc

I have powershell 4 and would like to install selective windows features for example only install File Server FS-FileServer  and File Server Resource Manager FS-Resource-Manager.

> [X] File and Storage Services FileAndStorage-Services  Installed
>             [X] File Server FS-FileServer Installed
>             [X] File Server Resource Manager  FS-Resource-Manager Installed

for this my sample code looks like this

```
Configuration JSwebDeploy2
{ 
   Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

    node "localhost"
    { 

         WindowsFeature FS-FileServer
         {
            Name = "FS-FileServer"
            Ensure = 'Present'

         }
          WindowsFeature FS-Resource-Manager
         {
            Name = "FS-Resource-Manager"
            Ensure = 'Present'

         }
    }
} 

JSwebDeploy2
```

Is this the correct way to go about doing with or is there a way to group all sub features together. I came across WindowsFeatureSet but that is only avaliable in Powershell 5.0 onward.

Comment: If you are going to get into Desired State Configuration I strongly recommend upgrading to the latest version of Windows Management Framework, which would move you to at least PowerShell 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use version 5 in general, as TheMadTechnician said, but you can group the features, in a way, by generating the config in a loop:

```
Configuration JSwebDeploy2
{ 
   Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

    node "localhost"
    { 

         @('FS-FileServer','FS-Resource-Manager').ForEach({

             WindowsFeature $_
             {
                Name = $_
                Ensure = 'Present'
             }
         }
    }
} 

JSwebDeploy2
```

Use your loop construct of choice, and likely you'd want to parameterize the config instead of hardcoding the array, maybe use `-ConfigurationData` etc., but the concept is the same: use looping and variables when you build/generate your config.

This is just a side note, but version 5 has way more features for debugging and testing configurations, including the `Invoke-DscResource` cmdlet; very useful.

But beware that `WindowsFeatureSet` is a Composite resource, which is not supported by that particular cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it is very helpful. Could you please elaborate on which particular cmdlet is not supported for WindowsFeatureSet?

Comment: I would prefer to use powershell 5 if allowed. could you offer a suggestion where I have 2 foreach groups where one is dependent on another. If I keep one foreach group below the other does it guarantee they will be executed sequentially?

Comment: @kumar as far as I know, it's only `Invoke-DscResource` that doesn't support `Composite` resources. It's not a problem for regular DSC use. It could come up if you use DSC resources with another configuration management system like Chef or Puppet, because their implementation may use `Invoke-DscResource`, but I'm not certain on that. Also, you can use `Get-DscResource` to see the available resources on the system and what type they are. To see all composite resources: `Get-DscResource | ? { $_.ImplementedAs -eq 'Composite' }`

Comment: @kumar for your second question, you can never guarantee the execution order in DSC based on the order that you put them in the file. You should always use the `DependsOn` property of each resource to enforce execution order. You will have to work that into the looping.